# Closing MacBook lid to sleep with Amphetamine (Monterey)

Tags: macos, sleep, macbook, lid, keepalive

[Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704) is a fairly popular Mac program for keeping Macs awake (not sleeping). The program is also used to use MacBooks in "clamshell" mode; using the MacBook while closed with peripheral devices.

However, I don't use clamshell mode and I would actually like my MacBook to go to sleep when the lid is closed even if Amphetamine is running. Basically have

Closing lid to sleep > Amphetamine settings

I looked around in the settings, but I couldn't find this option. Is this possible? I'm open to trying other programs as well.

Comment: Out of context, this title sounded super weird ^^

Comment: If the point of Amphetamines is to keep your Mac running, I don't see the point if your question. Stop Amphetamines from running.

Comment: Sorry, my use case is that if I would enable Amphetamines on by default and leave my laptop open if I don't want it to sleep. Then have my laptop sleep when I close to lid and put it in my bag or whatever. I wouldn't want my Mac to keep running and getting cooked inside the bag.

So basically, a manual switch to turn sleep on and off via the lid lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option should do what you want:

Amphetamine > Preferences… >
Closed Display Mode: ☑️ Allow system sleep when display is closed

Comment: Ah, I didn't see this; maybe because it's greyed out for me. There is [another thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/macapps/comments/wj6vej/amphetamine_clamshell_mode_is_not_working/) and it seems it's greyed out for all MacBook Air M2. But since it's already checked, maybe this automatically does what I want for me. Thanks!

Comment: after restart, it stay checked even if previously uncheck